# Android - Why is my client caching network calls?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This might be a weird question but I have reasons to believe my retrofit client is caching my calls. Why do I think so? I am using CoinGecko as my data provider. It has a limit of 10-30 network calls per minute per IP address. My android app is failing all calls for many minutes once it fails, but my iOS app succeeds when a minute is over.
Is something wrong with my code below? I really appreciate all answers

```
object RetrofitBuilder {

    private const val BASE_URL = "http://localhost/"

    private fun getRetrofit(): Retrofit {

        val httpClient = OkHttpClient
            .Builder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .cache(null)
            .addInterceptor { chain ->
                val response = chain.proceed(chain.request())
                response
                    .newBuilder()
                    .header("cache-control", "no-cache")
                    .build()
            }
            .build()

        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(httpClient)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(ResultCallAdapterFactory())
            .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
    }

    val apiService: ApiService = getRetrofit().create(ApiService::class.java)
}
```